# I get an Exception when trying to read an excel

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to read a simple .xlsx in java:

```
private void readExcelData(String excel) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(excel);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
}
```

but i get the following Exception in thread:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but class was expected
```

I had to add xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar or it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
```

Maybe it has something to do with that. I also added the compile and runtime depencies like someone suggested from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/4.1.0
But it didn't solve my problem

Does someone have a solution ?

Comment: Seems like compatibility issue, Could you please share the pom.xml file

Comment: there is no pom.xml file, and i've never heard of it. Could you guide me ?

Comment: irony is you have posted mavenrepository url and don't know pom.xml. So in simple words you have issue with jar included. if you can  list down the jars and version then people can help you.

Comment: You can work without xmlbean jar if you have added poi library.

Comment: Are you managing dependencies through Ant? Gradle? something else? The "pom.xml" file mentioned above is one of the standard approaches. You mentioned adding xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar and (in your answer) poi-oomxml. How are you adding these?

Answer (score 3):

Stupid mistake. I didn't add the most recent version of poi-oomxml